# export to PDF hangs in angular ui grid

Tags: angularjs

I am using angular ui grid for a table with more than 20 columns and about 1000 rows. But whenever I try to export to PDF option of table menu, it hangs. Even it hangs of tutorial site. Try http://ui-grid.info/docs/#/tutorial/401_AllFeatures .
Some examples with smaller data, fewer columns work well, like example 312 & 121.
But large examples hang for forever. How to resolve this problem?

Answer (score 1):

If you have any trouble printing more than 500 rows, like hang outs, please note there is a bug in the pdfmake.js library that is used by the ui-grid component. For this, you have a [Workaround](https://github.com/bpampuch/pdfmake/issues/280#issuecomment-98944706) at github.

Also please refer to this [Stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32491801/how-to-print-angular-ui-grid-entire-data/37058202#37058202) thread. It can help.