# Angular UI Grid - how to add an image to the top of the exported PDF?

Tags: angular-ui-grid

I'm using [Angular UI Grid](http://ui-grid.info/) and I've tried to few ways to add an image (logo) to the top of the PDF document which gets exported.

I've had no luck with the implementations I've tried...

```
exporterPdfHeader: { text: "My Header", image: "<urlOfImage>" }
exporterPdfHeader: { text: "My Header", backgroundImage: "<urlOfImage>" }
exporterPdfHeader: { text: "My Header", backgroundImage: url("<urlOfImage>") }
```

Is this even possible to do?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: @Mike - attempts included in my question above.

Comment: How were you able to get this to work in the end?

Answer (score 1):

Can you add your image inside a custom html header using `headerTemplate: 'header-template.html',` in grid-options?

See example [ui-grid tutorial](http://ui-grid.info/docs/#/tutorial/302_custom_header)

**edit**

OK,  having looked at the source and docs for the export,  there is nothing there about passing images in the header.

It does refer you to [pdfMake](https://github.com/bpampuch/pdfmake/blob/master/README.md)

> Images

This is simple. Just use the { image: '...' } node type.

JPEG and PNG formats are supported.

```
var docDefinition = { 
   content: [ 
       { // you'll most often use dataURI images on the browser side // if no width/height/fit is provided, the original size will be used image: 'data:image/jpeg;base64,...encodedContent...' },
       { // if you specify width, image will scale proportionally image: 'data:image/jpeg;base64,...encodedContent...', width: 150 }, 
       { // if you specify both width and height - image will be stretched image: 'data:image/jpeg;base64,...encodedContent...', width: 150, height: 150 }, 
       { // you can also fit the image inside a rectangle image: 'data:image/jpeg;base64,...encodedContent...', fit: [100, 100] }, 
       { // if you reuse the same image in multiple nodes, // you should put it to to images dictionary and reference it by name image: 'mySuperImage' }, 
       { // under NodeJS (or in case you use virtual file system provided by pdfmake) // you can also pass file names here image: 'myImageDictionary/image1.jpg' } ], 
  images: { 
      mySuperImage: 'data:image/jpeg;base64,...content...' } }
```

**end of quote**

So it looks like you were close.

Can you try a relative path from the root of your website wrapped in single quotes.

Comment: @user1135192 - How did you managed to get your image in the pdf in the end?

Answer (score 0):

Had to write a custom export function to add page margins.

[Plnkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/WrquhadoMkwxacFnTtYW?p=preview)

```
$scope.export = function() {
    var exportColumnHeaders = uiGridExporterService.getColumnHeaders($scope.gridApi.grid, uiGridExporterConstants.ALL);
    var exportData = uiGridExporterService.getData($scope.gridApi.grid, uiGridExporterConstants.ALL, uiGridExporterConstants.ALL, true);
    var docDefinition = uiGridExporterService.prepareAsPdf($scope.gridApi.grid, exportColumnHeaders, exportData);

    docDefinition.pageMargins = [40, 80, 40, 60];   

    if (uiGridExporterService.isIE() || navigator.appVersion.indexOf("Edge") !== -1) {
      uiGridExporterService.downloadPDF($scope.gridOptions.exporterPdfFilename, docDefinition);
    } else {
      pdfMake.createPdf(docDefinition).open();
    }
  }
```

Image has to be provided as base 64 encoded, unless using Node.js (as per pdfmake library).
Otherwise, you may need to use a JavaScript function to download and convert an image to base 64.

References:

- https://stackoverflow.com/a/37058202/2808230
- pdfExport function in http://ui-grid.info/release/ui-grid.js
- Found this as I was writing up this answer: [Angular UI Grid - Exporting an image to a pdf](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42981314/angular-ui-grid-exporting-an-image-to-a-pdf)